# Drawing a circle to a surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I'm writing a program in pygame in which I want to draw circles on several surfaces, so that when I erase a circle (redraw it with the transparent colorkey) I get the picture that was in the layer below back. However, I seem to be stuck at an early step and can't seem to draw a circle on a surface (as opposed to the background display). Here is a minimal example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width  = 400
height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
surf1 = pygame.Surface((width,height))
surf1.fill((0,255,0))
pygame.draw.circle(surf1, (0,0,0), (200,2000), 5)
screen.blit(surf1, (0,0))
exit = False

while not exit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I expected to get a green surface with a black circle in the middle, but I only get a green surface. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in the coordinates for the circle, it should be `pygame.draw.circle(surf1, (0,0,0), (200,200), 5)`, i.e. a `200` instead of a `2000`. Oh, and you get a green surface, not a green circle ;)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem! And yes, I meant green surface, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Don't post answers in the comments, @ThomasKühn, post them as answers.

Comment: @AdamBarnes It was just a typo, but ok.

Comment: You're correct, it was as simple as a typo, but posting answers in the comments - no matter how simple - bypasses the quality controls such as up and downvoting, and marking as accepted, that answers have.  Plus, you don't get any sweet points for it.

Comment: Also, typos are off-topic, so this question should have been closed in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

You have a typo in the coordinates for the circle, it should be

```
pygame.draw.circle(surf1, (0,0,0), (200,200), 5)
```

i.e. a `200` instead of a `2000`.